# Is it possible to create a function that accepts Option<string> or Option<&str> as a parameter in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to create a function that accepts `Option<String>` or `Option<&str>` as a parameter in Rust?
Here is my test, but the compiler report errors.

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new<S: Into<Option<String>>>(name: S) -> Person {
        Person { name: name.into().unwrap_or("unknown".to_string()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person1 = Person::new(Some("Test"));
    let person2 = Person::new(Some("Test".to_string()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get always an `Option` but with different inner types. The function signature should mirror that:

```rust
fn new<S: ToString>(name: Option<S>) -> Person {}
```

I changed the generic type from `Into<String>` to [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) because `ToString` "is automatically implemented for any type which implements the Display trait" and with that your function could accept many more different types.

Due to having an `Option` I would proceed as following:

Convert the inner type of the `Option` (`S`) to `String`

```rust
name.map(|name| name.to_string()
```

Unwrap the Option with a default value

```rust
.unwrap_or_else(|| "unknown".to_string())
```

I used `unwrap_or_else` instead of `unwrap_or` because `unwrap_or` calls the function `to_string` even if the `Option` is `Some`, but `unwrap_or_else` only if the `Option` is `None`.

Full code:

```rust
fn new<S: ToString>(name: Option<S>) -> Person {
    Person {
        name: name
            .map(|name| name.to_string())
            .unwrap_or_else(|| "unknown".to_string()),
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd still use `Into<String>`, not `ToString`. The latter seems far too generic for this use case; you probably don't want to allow passing a number to the name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my test, but the compiler report errors.

Reminder: Rust's compiler is a rather helpfull fellow, when it complains reading its errors is useful, and when you ask for help *posting those errors* is also useful, to the reader.

Here the error is reasonably clear:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<String>: From<Option<&str>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:31
   |
14 |     let person1 = Person::new(Some("Test"));
   |                   ----------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Option<&str>>` is not implemented for `Option<String>`
   |                   |
   |                   required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Option<&'a T> as From<&'a Option<T>>>
             <Option<&'a mut T> as From<&'a mut Option<T>>>
             <Option<T> as From<T>>
```

Meaning there is no `Option` -> `Option` implemented via `From`/`Into`, so that's a dead end.

But since `Option` is a concrete type you don't actually need a "built-in" conversion from `Option<A>` to `Option<B>`, instead you can just use `Option::map` and call an existing `A -> B` conversion function:

```rust
        Person { name: name.map(Into::into).unwrap_or("unknown".to_string()) }
```

Incidentally there's a type that's pretty much made for this (not the `Option` bit but the "might be a string or a reference [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

Incidentally: `a.unwrap_or(b.to_string())` is rather bad style (and *clippy* warns against it): because Rust is an eager language, it's *always* going to allocate a string, even in the case where there's already one.